# How to inset near a mesh boundary without creating new border faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I was following a tutorial to create a helmet.

A the step for the mesh under the cube he insets a face to create an indent, but only insets the side of the mesh, not the open border.
How did he do it?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this using the 'Inset' tool.

Select the faces you want to inset:

[image]

Press <kbd>I</kbd> to trigger the 'Inset' tool and move the mouse to increase or decrease the amount. Press <kbd>B</kbd> during the inset to turn on the 'Boundary' option (which will stop creating faces along the boundary of the mesh):

[image]

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you are happy with the inset and then delete the inset faces with <kbd>X</kbd>*> Faces*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having problems after Ray's answer, check that you don't have a face on the boundary itself. Such faces can be hard to see so in edit mode, turn on x-ray mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>Z</kbd>) and use face-select (<kbd>3</kbd>) to see hidden faces.